# why gitkraken did not picking up .config

Tags: gitkraken

I have a config in `~/.ssh/config` for git with:

> **Host:** gitlab.test.com
>
> **Port:** 2224

And it is throwing the `connection refused` error.

Why `gitkraken` doesn't picking up it automatically ? If it's cannot be done, how to make `gitkraken` connect that git?

Answer (score 1):

The question has been a while but let me answer you:

> GitKraken does not currently respect your SSH config and cannot make use of any remote server nicknames or identities.  [GitKraken Support](https://support.gitkraken.com/integrations/authentication)